# Sybase: what device names does a database use?

Tags: database, sybase

Does anyone know how I can query the database to find what devices a database uses?

There is the sysdatabases table and the sysdevices table but I don't know how to link them

Anyone know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to run sp_helpdb against the database you're interested in:

```
1> sp_helpdb tempdb2
2> go
... other stuff here...
device_fragments               size          usage                created                   free     kbytes
------------------------------ ------------- -------------------- ------------------------- ----------------
tempdb2data                        2048.0 MB data only            Dec 17 2008 11:42AM                2086568
tempdb2log                         2048.0 MB log only             Dec 17 2008 11:42AM       not applicable
tempdb2log                         2048.0 MB log only             Dec 17 2008 11:42AM       not applicable
tempdb2data                        2048.0 MB data only            Dec 17 2008 11:43AM                2088960
tempdb2log                         4096.0 MB log only             Dec 17 2008 11:44AM       not applicable

--------------------------------------------------------------
log only free kbytes = 8355836
```

Comment: Thanks Adam. When I run the same command I get the following columns returned: name,db_size,owner,dbid,created,durability,status ... there is no device information! Our outputs are different. Do you know why? I'm using Sybase version 15.5

Comment: Docs for sp_helpdb are here for 15.5 http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/topic/com.sybase.infocenter.dc36273.1550/html/sprocs/X90458.htm and they suggest the same syntax.

Comment: I think the issue will be that sp_helpdb returns rows using a select and also prints out stuff. If you run it from the command line with isql it will display correctly. If you run it from the 15.5 version of Sql Advantage(not sure if name stayed, I've only used 12.x), then some data will be displayed in the grid and some on the "messages" output.

Comment: I'm an idiot! When I select "Results set 2" I can see what i need! Thanks a million Adam, really appreciate it

Comment: Hello Bob Can u please post what Sysbase SQL Query you are using to find what devices a database uses..Becase sp_helpdb TEST query return only following columns name,db_size,owner,dbid,created,durability,status

Answer (score 1):

1  Just a note re your first question.  If you `USE database` first, you will get even more detail in the report.

2  Do you still need the second question answered, how to link sysdatabase and sysdevices, as in, are you writing queries against the catalogue ?  If so, I need your ASE version, the answers are different.